# Keep getting "Input string not in correct format" when trying to read data from a text file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader, formatexception

I've had the error when I was still using double.parse or int.parse in place of `ConvertToDouble` and `ConvertToInt32`, respectively. 
Here's the code:

```
         ArrayList Webpages = new ArrayList();
         String FileName = "Medium.txt";
         StreamReader newSR = new StreamReader(FileName);
         while (!newSR.EndOfStream)
         {
             string[] data = (newSR.ReadLine()).Split(',');
             Webpage newEntry = new Webpage();
             newEntry.size = Convert.ToDouble(data[0]);
             newEntry.visitCount = Convert.ToInt32(data[1]);
             newEntry.name = data[2];
             Webpages.Add(newEntry);
         }
```

And the Textfile:

```
5.26,46,WebPage1
7.44,76,WebPage2
8.35,42,WebPage3
46.2,9,WebPage4
12.44,124,WebPage5
10.88,99,WebPage6
10.66,984,WebPage7
```

This is my error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
I'm getting the error message by the line that reads: `newEntry.size = Convert.ToDouble(data[0])`

Comment: Have you debugged to check what the value of `data[0]` is when it fails? (I'm wondering whether you're reading a blank line at the end of the file.) Is it possible that you're in a culture where the decimal separate is `,` rather than `.`?

Comment: tried your code, its working except I didnt used your Webpage newentry object, what is it ??

Answer (score 3):

Computer culture effect your delimeter types. In this case if delimeter is `.` you can add InvariantCulture options.

```
    newEntry.size = Convert.ToDouble(data[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also end of file may leads error if there is empty line. This way can be more secure.

```
 while (!newSR.EndOfStream)
 {
     string line = newSR.ReadLine();
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)
         break;
     string[] data = (line).Split(',');
     ............
```

Comment: neither `double.Parse` nor `Convert.ToDouble` throw a `System.FormatException` if the delimiter is `,` or `.`. They simply parse the value wrong. So culture dependent delimiter cannot be the problem here